# CompilationRelaxations attribute not working

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple console application in .net 4.5.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s1 = "s1";
        string s2 = "s1";

        Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(s1, s2));
    }
}
```

This gives true because of string interning. However, when I add the CompilationRelaxations attribute to the AssemblyInfo file, I'm still seeing true as the output.

[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(CompilationRelaxations.NoStringInterning)]

Even adding the attribute to my Program class does not seem to change the output.
[CompilationRelaxations(CompilationRelaxations.NoStringInterning)]

Changing it to a .net 4.0 application does not have any effect either.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is a pure guess, but chances are that the compiler optimizes the two string constants for you, before the interning gets a chance to do its thing at runtime. Try adding a separate class, in a separate file, and make a function `public static string s1() {return "s1";}` to it. Then call that function fro your `main`, and compare the result to an `"s1"` constant defined inside `"main"`. My guess is that this would compare equal only with the interning turned on.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I don't think so. Adding `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quote from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilationrelaxations.aspx):

> Marks an assembly as not requiring string-literal interning.

It doesn't prevent the compiler from doing string interning, just providing a hint that it's not required. The documentation for it is quite poor, both in MSDN and the CLI spec. See also this [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/c1c1d969-8d6b-4aaf-b7f4-3febedf3cd18/).